# btrfs not distributing data to smaller disks in 4-disk RAID1 array

Tags: linux, raid, btrfs

I have a `btrfs` filesystem composed of four disks of sizes 3TB, 3TB, 1TB, and 1TB, configured in a RAID1 (data and metadata).

I've noticed that `btrfs` doesn't seem to want to use the smaller disks at all:

```
# btrfs fi show /butter
Label: none  uuid: 6d899bb3-e7c1-4fc8-a20e-8a854dd39e21
        Total devices 4 FS bytes used 956.38GiB
        devid    1 size 931.51GiB used 0.00B path /dev/sdb1
        devid    2 size 931.51GiB used 0.00B path /dev/sda1
        devid    3 size 2.73TiB used 965.03GiB path /dev/sdd
        devid    4 size 2.73TiB used 965.03GiB path /dev/sde

btrfs-progs v4.0.1
```

Why is this?  At what point will it start putting data on the smaller disks?

It seems like it would be more efficient for `btrfs` to try to keep all of the disks at the same disk usage percentage so that I/O could be distributed among more devices, but maybe I'm missing something...  Is this behavior configurable?

---

Update: Since I originally asked this question I've swapped out some disks and added enough data to the pool now that it *has* started using the smaller disks:

```
Label: none  uuid: 32a5c215-4a58-4686-9b3b-b30a5ee1fda0
        Total devices 4 FS bytes used 1.74TiB
        devid    1 size 931.51GiB used 141.00GiB path /dev/sda
        devid    2 size 931.51GiB used 141.00GiB path /dev/sdb
        devid    3 size 2.73TiB used 1.84TiB path /dev/sdd
        devid    4 size 2.73TiB used 1.84TiB path /dev/sde
```

So `btrfs` *is* doing what I expected it to do (distribute data across all disks in the pool), it just kicked in much later than I had expected.  I'd be curious to know how it decides to distribute the data across disks, and if any of that is tuneable.

Comment: Have you run [`btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /butter`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Conversion)?

Comment: Also, RAID1 makes 2 copies of all the data. You have more than enough disks to do that. It sounds like you want 4 copies of all your data?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you ran [`btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -mconvert=raid1 /butter`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices#Conversion), your results are expected.

From the BTRFS Wiki's [SysadminGuide#RAID and data replication](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#RAID_and_data_replication):

> With RAID-1 and RAID-10, only two copies of each byte of data are written, regardless of how many block devices are actually in use on the filesystem.

You have more than enough disks to have two copies of your data.

Perhaps you want 4 copies of all your data? [N-way mirroring is a planned feature.](https://www.reddit.com/r/btrfs/comments/53hp06/btrfs_raid_1_sanity_checks/d7t9b7c/)

Play around with [this](http://carfax.org.uk/btrfs-usage/).

Comment: I just want two copies of my data, not four.  I know only two copies are being stored, which is fine.  My question was more about why btrfs doesn't distribute the data (still just two copies) across more disks to reduce i/o on any particular disk.

Comment: @mgalgs You should use a striped RAID level (RAID-0, RAID-10, RAID-5, RAID-6), then. Since you have ≥4 drives, try RAID-10 (striped mirror): `btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid10 -mconvert=raid10 /butter`

Comment: Sure, but I think you may have still misunderstood my question.  I understand that striped RAIDs distribute writes across all disks, I just thought it was curious that RAID-1 wouldn't utilize disks in its pool more proportionately.  In theory RAID-1 should be able to distribute its writes across disks in the pool.  BTW, since asking this question nearly 3 years ago I've added enough data to the pool that it *has* started sending data to the smaller disks.  So `btrfs` _does_ do this already, I was just surprised it didn't kick in earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I do not remember where, but I think I remember something that I read some time ago somewhere. It would lend light to your question, the main concept is:

- BTRFS (RAID1 level) writes first on the disk with more free space, then on the next one (excluding the one that has written onto) just to write both copies on different disks.

Disks are not physical disks, they are 'devices' it has (this disclaimer is for people using multiple partitions on the same physical disk, like /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb1 ...), that is why it highly avoidable having more than one partition on the same disk assigned to the same BTRFS; you are killing BTRFS ability to write (both copies of RAID1 level) on different physical media.

In other words, until free space on all the rest of disks is not below the size of then smallest ones, BTRFS will not use them (on RAID1 level), since it will choose the ones with higher free space.

Another way to say it is BTRFS tries to let the same free space on all RAID1 level disks, when it needs space BTRFS takes it from the disk with most free space on it.

And that can be confirmed by your typed data report:

```
devid    1 size 931.51GiB used 141.00GiB path /dev/sda
devid    2 size 931.51GiB used 141.00GiB path /dev/sdb
devid    3 size 2.73TiB used 1.84TiB path /dev/sdd
devid    4 size 2.73TiB used 1.84TiB path /dev/sde
```

Just by doing some math:

```
A) 2.73TiB - 1.84TiB = 0.89TiB       <-- close to what is free
B) 931.51GiB = 0.9292TiB             <-- Just convert the size units
C) 141.00GiB = 0.1377TiB             <-- Just convert the size units
D) 0.9292TiB - 0.1377TiB = 0.7915TiB <-- close to what is free
and 0.7915TiB is very similar to 0.89TiB, so free space is now balanced
```

Until you fill 2.73TiB-931.51GiB=1.8TiB, it will not use your smallest one.